# Thread Abort Exception. from mail page to logout page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Below is my code. which runs well with session handling. But the problem is when I click logout button on masterpage I get an error :

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.

Needed help on how to `redirect` back to login page if I click logout button from masterpage..

Below code is from my main `aspx` file which is with `masterpage`.

```
  protected async void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["mail"] == null)
        {

            Response.Redirect("~/login.aspx", false);
            Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
        else
        {

            await Task.Run(() => retrivelast());
         }
     }
```

Below is code in master page for logout event

```
    protected void LinkButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("mail",                ""));
        Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
    }
```

Where linkbutton2_click is my logout event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `Response.redirect("login.aspx");` with
the following:

```
Response.Redirect("login.aspx", false);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
Visible = false;
```

Your problem is that the default redirect calls another method which throws a ThreadAbortException.

For more information on this approach (and a more generic solution), see :

https://www.codeproject.com/tips/561490/asp-net-response-redirect-without-threadabortexcep

Another option is catching the ThreadAbortException.